# Magento 2 Shipping Method fail to load due the http 500 error

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, http-error-500

The shipping method failed to load after I complete setup the payment method and so on... None of the method shown in the frontend and a error log shown as below

http://domain/Magento2/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/o5DzNV7FmLFXLua4B2OusRbkHRJcIpfc/estimate-shipping-methods

The inspect show *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)*

can someone help me to solve this problem....